# MySQL - mysqli_connect() returns "too many connections" error, worked fine yesterday and no changes were made?

Tags: php, mysql

This one kills me every time it happens: something that worked just fine the last time it was run doesn't work the next time I try to run it and no changes were made anywhere in the script. Especially this issue because other times it had been awhile since I ran the script so changes had been made in included files that caused the script to not work, but this time, it worked yesterday when I logged off for the day but when I log back on today, it doesn't all of a sudden. Because that makes sense, right?!

The script's functionality is to display data for products stored in MySQL database along with search & sorting options for the more than 1600 products stored(this will be over 14,000 in the future so this needs to be fixed/optimized now to prevent future issues). It's largely unfinished but the main function, displaying the table and data, worked fine yesterday. Also, when I went to check for errors, I discovered an error_log with over 300MB-worth of two repeating errors:

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections in ...
mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in ...
```

I had received this error once before and did some searching to discover that I never closed any of my connections. After adding `mysqli_close($db)` to all of my functions that opened a connection, the error went away and everything was fine. Now it's throwing the error again even with `mysqli_close($db)` and I'm at a loss here. And on top of that, I don't understand why it throws this error and continuously repeats till I stop the page reloading instead of just ending the process with one error reported.

#### Products Table Script

```
function dispTable($var) {
    require 'db-inc.php'; // << Database connection file
    require 'dlc-forms.php'; // << Holds $search_bar and $view_per_page forms
    // Define and validate variables
    $currentpage=$order_by=$limit_view=$query=$column=$direction='';
    getVars();
    // Query
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl" . $query . $order_by . $limit_view;
    $res=mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    // Display result count
    if (($var == 'results') && (isset($_GET['q']))) {$res_count='Search returned ' . $count . ' results.';}
    // Loop through result set
    if ($var == 'table') {echo '
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    // Not sure about having 2 table headers, but I want
                    // the search bar to be right above the header row.
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="2">' . $search_bar . '</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>' . sortBtn('id') . '</th>
                    <th>' . sortBtn('title') . '</th>
                    <th>' . $view_per_page . '</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $id=$row['id'];
                $title=$row['title'];
                $link=$row['link'];
                echo '<tr><td>' . $id . '</td><td>' . $title . '</td><td>' . $link . '</td></tr>';
             } echo '
             </tbody>
             <tfoot>';
            // Display pagination
            if (($var == 'pages') && (isset($_GET['view']))) {pagination();}echo '
            </tfoot>
        </table>';
    } mysqli_close($db);
}
```

#### Scripts For Reference

```
function getVars() {
    $x='0';     $r='0';     $row=array();           $range='3';
    $num='item_num';        $name='item_name';      $btn='item_btn';
    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
        return $search=checkData(trim($_GET['search']));
        return $query=" WHERE title LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['col'])) {
        return $col=checkData(trim($_GET['col']));
    }
    if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
        return $dir=checkData(trim(strtoupper($_GET['sort'])));
        return $order_by=" ORDER BY " . $col . " " . $dir;
    }
    if ((isset($_GET['view'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['view']))) {
        return $view=checkData(trim($_GET['view']));
        return $limit_view=" LIMIT 0," .  $view;
    }
    if ((isset($_GET['page'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['page']))) {
        return $page=checkData(trim($_GET['page']));
    }
}
function pagination() {
    $dbase='thesof73_dlc';
    require 'inc/db-inc.php';
    getVars();
    $tbl_total=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dlc_tbl"));
    $total=ceil($tbl_total/$view);
    $prev=$currentpage - 1;
    $next=$currentpage + 1;
    if ($currentpage > $total) {$currentpage=$total;}
    if ($currentpage < 1) {$currentpage=1;}
    if ($currentpage > 1) {echo '
        <li><a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?page=1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?page=' . $prev. '">Back</a></li>';
    }
    for ($x=($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
        if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total)) {
            if ($x == $currentpage) {
                echo '<li>' . $x . '</li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?page=' . $x . '">' . $x . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($currentpage != $total) {echo '
        <li><a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?page=' . $next . '">Next</a></li>
        <li><a class="material-icons" href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?page=' . $total . '">Last</a></li>';
    } mysqli_close($db);
}
function sortBtn($var) {
    if ($var == 'id') {$header='Item No.';}
    elseif ($var == 'title') {$header='Product Name';}
    getVars();
    $asc='asc';
    $desc='desc';
    if ((isset($_GET['sort'])) && ($col == $var)) {
        if ($dir == 'desc') {
            return '<a id="sort" href="?q=' . $q . '&sort=' . $desc . '&col=' . $var . '">' . $header . '&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-sort-' . $desc . '"></span></a>';
        } elseif ($dir == 'asc') {
            return '<a id="sort" href="?q=' . $q . '&sort=' . $asc . '&col=' . $var . '">' . $header . '&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-sort-' . $asc . '"></span></a>';
        }
    } else {
        return '<a id="sort" href="?q=' . $q . '&sort=' . $desc . '&col=' . $var . '">' . $header . '&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-sort"></span></a>';
    }
}
```

I know it's a mess to look at, even worse before I put pieces of the code into functions, but I'm only providing the code for reference seeing as it worked fine yesterday. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that `dispTable()` the only function on your page needing database access? or are you opening a database connection in multiple functions? If the latter: open just one connection per request (not per function).

Comment: @Sirko - Like I said, it worked as-is yesterday but I went ahead and tried that and no change.

Comment: "it worked" in those cases sometimes means you were just lucky. I would try to solve the underlying problem and not just fiddle around on symptoms.

Comment: @Sirko - Novel idea! If I only knew the underlying problem, that's exactly what I would do...